# How to detect safari 15 overscroll page refresh programatically?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

Is there any way to know that page reload is triggered by "pull to refresh" gesture in Safari **in JS**? I noticed that such reload has a different behavior in the subject of scroll positions. For example, when I do some `window.scrollTo` right after pageload it behaves a bit different based on which was the trigger of a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library that seems to be able to identify if a refresh was initiated based on scroll.

https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js